# ReportViewer.dwp not working - Session state has been disabled

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I'm getting this error while try to open ReportViewer.dwp:

```
Message : Name=Request (GET:http://xxxxxxxx/_layouts/WPPrevw.aspx?ID=64)
Message : Site=/
Message : Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=8.7358
Message : Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SessionDisabledException: Session state 
      has been disabled for ASP.NET.  The Report Viewer control requires th
      at session state be enabled in local mode.    at Microsoft.Reporting.
      WebForms.ReportViewer.EnsureSessionOrConfig()     at Microsoft.Report
      ing.WebForms.SessionKeepAliveOperation.CreateRequest(ReportViewer vie
      wer)     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewerClientScript.Set
      ViewerInfo(ReportViewer viewer, String reportAreaId, String promptAre
      aRowId, String docMapAreaId, String fixedTableId, String promptSplitt
      erId, String docMapSplitterId, String docMapHeaderOverflowId, String 
      directionCacheId, String browserModeCacheId)     at Microsoft.Reporti
      ng.WebForms.ReportViewer.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.U
      I.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.P
      reRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRec
      ursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInter
      nal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     a
      t System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.We
      b.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Contro
      l.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRender
      RecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveIn
      ternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()   
        at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System
      .Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Con
      trol.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRen
      derRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiv
      eInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
           at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at Sys
      tem.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPo
      int, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.
      ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean include
      StagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at ASP
      ._layouts_wpprevw_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at Sys
      tem.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpAppli
      cation.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.Exe
      cuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   Message : Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://xxxxx/_layouts
      /WPPrevw.aspx?ID=64)). Execution Time=70.1226
```

I must be missing some configuration step. Can anyone provide guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that the session management service is actually disabled/not provisioned as the message suggest.

If that is the case, you can enable/reate it by using the PowerShell command

```
Enable-SPSessionStateService -Defaultprovision
```

This will provision a new service with the default configuration. If you need to change some of the parameter, please have a look at Microsoft official documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607857.aspx). Also notice that you will need to run the above command as a farm admin.